# Android Studio FCM Token doesn't work for all of my projects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I test the tokens of my projects with ARC. I get the token of the Project 1 and it gives me good results. but I try the project 2 token and it appears "NotRegistered" result. How can I create a new token for project 2?
Both projects are linked to the same Firebase database

Token of project 1:

```
{
"multicast_id": 7232114524318539000,
"success": 1,
"failure": 0,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
  {
"message_id": "0:1563412417975067%580b2476f9fd7ecd"
}
],
}
```

Token of project 2:

```
{
"multicast_id": 
8668357259345171000
,
"success": 0,
"failure": 1,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
  {
"error": "NotRegistered"
}
],
}
```

any idea?

Edit: 
Generating new server key does not solve it either, the same result keeps appearing

Comment: Make sure that both Android apps are registered within the same Firebase project that you use for sending the messages.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, they are registered in the same firebase project and both projects appear in google-services.json

Comment: I assume you mean that both **apps** appear in the google-services.json, as there's only one project. In that case I'm not sure what could be causing the token to be unregistered for one of the apps. I hope somebody else sees it.

Answer (score 0):

it was an emulator bug, it was to use it before implementing FCM